# Do I need Open and Close methods with a IDisposable class?

Tags: c#, class-design, idisposable

I'm working on a simple repository class on top of a ADO.NET SQL connection. The class is sealed and implements the IDisposable pattern.

I intended to keep it simple so I open the SQL connection in the constructor and closed through the Dispose() method so it can be used with the using statment.

```
using (var r = new MyRepository(connectionString))
{
    ...
}
```

I originally had a pair of Open/Close method for this class but I found it makes the class much harder to implement and also more confusing to use.

Do you typically have Open/Close methods for your repository class? If so why?

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN Dispose Pattern guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> CONSIDER providing method Close(), in addition to the Dispose(), if
>   close is standard terminology in the area. When doing so, it is
>   important that you make the Close implementation identical to Dispose
>   and consider implementing the IDisposable.Dispose method explicitly

So, taking into account that open-close terminology is often used in database interactions, your idea to have them is good and quite viable.

**But**, if their implementation and use makes your classes much more complex to no or minimal advantages then do not create them. In the end you always know your system and requirements better, so you should base your decisions on your concrete situation, not on abstract guidelines and principles.

**P.S.:** Whether you have these methods or not, your system should open connections for smallest possible amount of time and close them as soon as they are no longer needed. And it is often difficult to accomplish when you have to put some special disposal code in the end of each use.

Comment: +1. Good link/guidance... Whether "open/close" are expected behaviors for repository (unlike database/file) is personal choice (would not be my choice). Good point on not making code harder to use for some optional guidance.

Comment: A repository is not (expected to 'look' like) a connection. The purpose of a Repository is to hide such details, so I would _not_ add Open/Close.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not implementing `IDisposable` directly on your repository class.

Instead, obtain and release resources as necessary within each method of the repository.

```
public class MyRepostory : IRepository
{
     public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
     {
          using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
          {
              connection.Open();
              // ... get the data, etc. ...
              return foos;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good for a detached (server) solution, less so for a more stateful bussineslayer.